# python pairing family with scipy

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

following
[Python algorithm with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70016216/python-algorithm-with-numpy)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
import collections
from scipy.sparse import csgraph

maxdist = 2.
pairings=((1,2),(1,4),(3,2),(3,10),(6,2),(5,8),(5,4),(5,3),(7,10),(7,11),(8,7),(20,21),(20,22))

pairings = np.array(pairings)
node_to_id = np.unique(np.sort(np.ravel(pairings)))
id_to_node = {id_: node for node, id_ in enumerate(node_to_id)}
n_nodes = len(node_to_id)
dok_mat = sparse.dok_matrix((n_nodes, n_nodes), dtype=bool)
for left, right in pairings:
    row, col = id_to_node[left], id_to_node[right]
    dok_mat[row, col] = True
    dok_mat[col, row] = True # undirected graph
csr_mat = dok_mat.tocsr()
del dok_mat
_, components = csgraph.connected_components(csr_mat)
families = collections.defaultdict(list)
for id_, component in zip(node_to_id, components):
    families[component].append(id_)

print("families", list(families.values()))

shortest_paths = csgraph.shortest_path(csr_mat)
for id_, row in zip(node_to_id, shortest_paths):
    immediate_family = node_to_id[row <= maxdist]
    print(id_, "  -  ",immediate_family,"family")
```

Hi again,

I've been running this code now for a while and it works.
But I noticed that there's room for improvement.
Now the maxdist is set to 2, but it will start at pairing (1,2) so the last won't be in this family.

When it is started on 3 pairing they are all family based on the maxdist of 2.

Is there a way to avoid this issue by giving the best possible family combination based on the maxdist?

I ran above code, and I need to get the best family. Based on the pairings and maxdist=2 they should all be family when starting with the 3 pairs.

OUTPUT maxdist=2:

```
families [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11], [20, 21, 22]]
1   -   [1 2 3 4 5 6] family
2   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6 10] family
3   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10] family
4   -   [1 2 3 4 5 8] family
5   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  7  8 10] family
6   -   [1 2 3 6] family
7   -   [ 3  5  7  8 10 11] family
8   -   [ 3  4  5  7  8 10 11] family
10   -   [ 2  3  5  7  8 10 11] family
11   -   [ 7  8 10 11] family
20   -   [20 21 22] family
21   -   [20 21 22] family
22   -   [20 21 22] family
```

family member 3 has the biggest family based on de maxdist=2, so all other members should have that family.
If the family is equally big take the smallest number.

so number 11 will be lonely sheep.

EXPECTED OUTPUT maxdist=2:

```
families [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11], [20, 21, 22]]
1   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10] family
2   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10] family
3   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10] family
4   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10] family
5   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10] family
6   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10] family
7   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10] family
8   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10] family
10   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10] family
11   -   [ 11] family
20   -   [20 21 22] family
21   -   [20 21 22] family
22   -   [20 21 22] family
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT maxdist=3:

```
families [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11], [20, 21, 22]]
1   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10 11] family
2   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10 11] family
3   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10 11] family
4   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10 11] family
5   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10 11] family
6   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10 11] family
7   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10 11] family
8   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10 11] family
10   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10 11] family
11   -   [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10 11] family
20   -   [20 21 22] family
21   -   [20 21 22] family
22   -   [20 21 22] family
```

*edit made the example pairing better

Comment: Can you show what this prints and what you'd like for it to instead print?

Comment: I added it in the original post